# Kotlin object equals vs Java object equals

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I created a User class and on calling the equals on two objects with the same content

```
println("equals = ${User("Alex", 1).equals(User("Alex", 1))}")
```

outputs true but aren't the two objects different ?

same for Java gives false:

```
System.out.print("equals = "+new User("Alex",1).equals(new User("Alex",1)));
```

Comment: It depends on how the `equals` method is implemented inside the `User` class.

Comment: Have you actually implemented the `equals` method override? At this point this doesn't look like a Kotlin vs Java issue, does it.

Comment: no overrides, using the basic implementation which should compare memory locations ?

Comment: @ir2pid the `Object.equals` implementation compares references. Two separate invocations of `new User` will not share the same reference, regardless of the equal arguments given to the constructor. You simply need to implement `equals` appropriately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. If you have the same `User` class, you'll get the same result in both cases. I.e. if your Java code uses Kotlin `data class`, it will return `true`; if Kotlin code uses a Java (or Kotlin non-`data`) class without overridden `equals`, it will return `false`.
2. In Kotlin, unlike Java, it's better and safer to write `User("Alex", 1) == User("Alex", 1)`. This will call `equals` for non-null objects and handle `null` on the left side properly where Java will crash.

Answer (score 3):

I guess your `User` class is a `data class`? Then you get default implementation of comparing member variables for `equals`.

Comment: so kotlin data classes automatically compare every member variable for equivalence ?

Comment: Yes, they automatically generate an `equals` method, which deems two instances equal if all properties in the primary constructor pass an `equals` check for the two instances.